¿Mi proyecto se ha paralizado, pero no me da error de código que pueda ver, podran orientarme un poco?
uso Visual Estudio Code, como Lenguaje DART, Y como Framework Flutter, estoy realizando un proyecto pero el proyecto ya no quiere avanzar, no logro que me envíe los errores de login que he parametrizado, solo se queda en circularProgressIndicator, y de allí no avanza.
si le quito el breackpoint de seguridad de VScode, se queda procesando, no avanza y me erroja el siguiente error:

Error
dart-sdk/lib/internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
297:3  throw
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/convert_patch.dart 38:5
_parseJson  dart-sdk/lib/convert/json.dart 610:36                                        convert  dart-sdk/lib/convert/json.dart 216:41
decode  dart-sdk/lib/convert/json.dart 155:10
jsonDecode
packages/tv/app/data/services/remote/authentication_api.dart 26:11
  packages/tv/app/domain/either.dart 20:19
when  packages/tv/app/data/services/remote/authentication_api.dart
17:18           createRequestToken
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50
  dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54
runUnary  dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18
handleValue  dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 838:44
handleValueCallback  dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 867:13
_propagateToListeners  dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 643:5                                    [_completeWithValue]  dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 713:7
callback  dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11
_microtaskLoop  dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                              _startMicrotaskLoop  dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7


1.- He cerrado y vuelto a abrir el proyecto.
2.- he aplicado Flutter Doctor
3.- he repasado la codificación varias veces
Espero que logre avanzar del circularProgressIndicator

Bienvenido, agrega tu código por favor
